# About Closed Unit Balls

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

If $(X, \|\cdot \|_X)$ is a normed vector space over $\mathbb R$, then the closed unit ball of $X$ is given by

$$B(X)=\{x\in X: \|x \|_X \le 1\}.$$

If $X^{*}$ is the set of all bounded linear functionals on the normed space $(X, \|\cdot \|_X)$ then the closed unit ball of the normed space $(X^*, \|\cdot \|_{op})$ is given by

$$B(X^*)=\{f\in X^*:\|f \|_{op}\le 1\},$$

where

$$\|f \|_{op}=\sup\left\{\frac{|f(x)|}{\|x \|_X}: x\in X \mbox{ with }x \neq 0 \right\}.$$

Suppose now that $X$ is a locally convex (Hausdorff) topological vector space with $X^*$ as its topological dual space. How can we describe the closed unit balls of $X^*$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a normed spaces we also have
$$
\Vert f\Vert_{op}=\sup\left\{|f(x)|:x\in\operatorname{Ball}_X(0,1)\right\}
$$
hence
$$
\operatorname{Ball}_{X^*}(0,1)=\{f\in X^*:x\in\operatorname{Ball}_X(0,1)\implies |f(x)|\leq 1\}
$$

For general Hausdorff locally convex spaces there is no single norm describing its topology. But there several [seminorms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29) which all together saves the day. So you can not define unit ball of $X$, you can not talk about norms of functionals and as the consequence you can not talk about unit ball in $X^*$. But there is very close notion of [polar set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_set) defined as
$$
V'=\{f\in X^*:x\in V\implies |f(x)|\leq 1\}
$$
which is often can be suitable substitute for unit ball in dual space if you choose $V$ as neighbourhood of $0\in X$.

Comment: Are you still there? Anyway, thank you very much for such brilliant ideas.

Comment: If you have any questions feel free to ask